# Замедление работы сервера из-за запуска неизвестных процессов

Tags: mysql, процесс, magento

Я работаю с magento 1.9
Мой сервер автоматически включает процесс mysql, который загружает базу данных и процессор иногда на 120%, и некоторые другие процессы также работают, но я не могу понять, что это. из-за этого сайт тормозит

Я пытался убить процессы, но они запускаются снова, как я могу быть с этим. 
Как узнать что их запускает?
Помоги мне, пожалуйста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: php-fpm — это интерпретатор PHP. Тормозит он из-за того, что обрабатывает соответствующий код. mysqld тормозит, потому что обрабатывает соответствующим образом написанные выборки. С MySQL довольно просто — включить slowlog и подумать над долго обрабатывающимися запросами.

Comment: это маджентовские крон-джобы, дальше гуглите.